# X11: how to run an application after login?

Tags: linux, x11

Basically, I need run a graphical program after the user logins.

I tried adding a "test line" to ~/.xinitrc or to ~/xprofile but nothing happens:

```
exec /usr/bin/gedit &
```

I need to run my app in the "most used" desktop managers, that is why I'm trying to use X11.

What can I do?

Comment: For most of the later desktops, and wm (e.g. kdm, gdm, lxdm, kde, gnome, fluxbox, etc..) it will be desktop dependent using whatever the desktop session manager for any particular desktop may be.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "desktop managers", then they may overlook `.xinitrc`, using `.xsession` instead.  The `.xinitrc` file is used mainly by [`startx`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/startx.1.html), while [`xdm`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xdm.1.html) uses `.xsession`.

A quick check of [`gdm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/gdm.8.html) and [`kdm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/kdm.1.html) shows that they accomplish the same thing using differently-named files.  So "most used" may be difficult to achieve.

Here are a few related questions:

- *[xinitrc doesn't work, .xsessionrc does! (was ... Re: startx vs. xdm)](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/07/msg02117.html)*
- *[What is “.xsession” for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/what-is-xsession-for)*
- *[.xsession and .xinitrc not executed at login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162448/xsession-and-xinitrc-not-executed-at-login)*